# R to SAS: from glmer to PROC NLMIXED

Tags: r, sas, lme4, proc

I know my question might not be exactly on the usual SO topics, but I'm really desperate.
I've been trying to find what's wrong with my code for months.

I need the SAS equivalent with `PROC NLMIXED` to get the complete variance-covariance matrix of this model, written on R with `lme4::glmer` :

(after "poissonizing" my survival data with the library `surrosurv`, it looks like the snippet below. `var1`, `var2` and `cov` are factor variables)

```
 data_pois = surrosurv::poissonize(data, interval.width = interval.width, factors = c ('var1', 'var2', 'cov'), compress = FALSE)
head(data_pois)
     id event  var1    var2 cov         time interval
1225  1     0 -0.5       13   1 0.0005669899        0
822   2     1 -0.5        9   1 0.0947011826        0
611   3     1 -0.5        7   1 0.0951096974        0
235   4     1 -0.5        3   0 0.1028146920        0
1847  5     0 -0.5       19   1 0.1122793044        0
1321  6     1 -0.5       14   1 0.1298256694        0
    mod    =  lme4::glmer(
      formula = event ~ -1 + interval : factor(var1) + cov + offset(log(time))+ (0 + var1 | var2 ) + (1 | var2 ),
      data = data_pois, 
      family = poisson(link = "log"),
      control=glmerControl(optCtrl=list(maxfun=2e5), optimizer="bobyqa"))
```

The details of the covariate are:

- var1 : binary, -0.5 and 0.5 (example : treatment arm)
- var2 : categorical, 20 levels (example : countries, cohorts)
- time : continuous
- cov : binary, 0 and 1 (example : sex)
- interval : 2 levels, 0 and 10 according to the survival time of the individual

Comment: It would be possible to have a factor variable with a level of “-0.1” but better than presenting a print to console version is far inferior to using `str` or `dput` for unambiguous documentation of an object structure. Appears you want an answer that is in SAS, but presenting R code using unusual functions with no `library` calls presents a barrier to investigation as well.

Comment: You are right, I have made edits to add details on my covariate and the name of the library for the `poissonize` function

Comment: One other thing which I'm not sure about in my answer below - what is `var3`? You don't reference it anywhere other than in the second random effect, is this a typo?

Comment: Sorry, it's a typo error. I've correctedit, it is `var2`. I've added example for the variable I am using to have an example of context. Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want an overall independent random intercept and another set of correlated ones for each non-reference level of `var1`.

From the information that you provided and with my admittedly pretty superficial knowledge of both languages and the underlying statistics, I think the matching NLMIXED call could look something like this:

```
proc nlmixed data=data_pois;
   /* Create dummies as needed/desired - more will be required if >2 levels exist. */
   dummy_var1 = (var1 eq -0.5);
   dummy_cov = (cov eq 0);

   /* Random effects, see caveats below. */
   random r1 r2 ~ normal([0, 0], [rsig1, 0, rsig2]) subject=var2;

   /* Linear predictor. */
   eta = b1*interval + b2*dummy_var1*interval + b3*dummy_cov1 + r1*dummy_var1 + r2 + log(time);
   mu = exp(eta);

   /* Option 1: use built-in distribution. */
   model event ~ poisson(mu);
   /* Option 2: write out log-likelihood by hand. */
   ll = event * log(mu) - mu - lgamma(event + 1);
   model event ~ general(ll); /* The DV can be anything here, its value doesn't matter. */
run;
```

This is quite bare-bones, I would almost certainly add a `parms` statement to initialize model parameters to more sensible values such as those precomputed from a fixed effects-only model. It's usually also a good idea to express your variances in the log scale (which will double as a `bounds` statement) and add extra boundary checks before making any transformations. You'll probably want to include additional tuning and/or convergence options in the NLMIXED call as well.

Finally, returning to the random effects, it really depends on what you want to do here exactly. A limitation of PROC NLMIXED is that random effects have to be nested if you're adding more than one - this is not an issue here if you're using a single blocking level. It's still up to you to define how the additional levels of `r1` (to be added) covary if there's more than 2 levels of `var1`, I believe `glmer` makes this unstructured by default.

Comment: Is it not `exp(eta)` rather than `log(eta)` ? Thanks

Comment: You're right, that was a brainfart - I've updated the response. I've also removed the pieces on `var3` since that's no longer applicable.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've not yet tried to add the random effect with the slope (I got an error with the `r1*dummy_var1`  in the model : `Multiple SUBJECT= effects need to form a containment hierarchy, for example SUBJECT=A, SUBJECT=B(A), SUBJECT=C(A*B)`. But already with model with one random parameter only and the same method of estimation (GAUSS), I don't get the same results between R and SAS for the random estimate... I realy don't understand. I can add somewhere an example of the initial dataset

Comment: You can rewrite the random effect using a single statement with the same parametrization now that `var3` is out of the picture, I've made another edit. I do think it's going to be really quite difficult to get R and SAS to match numerically here, certainly for the random part..

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's now working ! I got the same estimates except for the random parameters (intercept) : 3.19 on R  vs. 2.19 on SAS for the standard deviation (the methods of estimations are not the same but this does not explain such a difference)

Comment: Just to thank you again, everything is perfect now. I got the same estimations from R, glmer and SAS PRC NLMIXED.